# Will i retain old data when I Modifying existing column name and choices?

Tags: list, document-library, column, rename

I am new to SharePoint. I need to modify some existing column names in List . I also need to change the choices names eg:

Column Name : Type
choices : Car, Bus, Truck

to

New Column name : Category
Choices : Two Tires, Four Tires, six tires

In above without deleting Type i renamed it to Category and removed old choices and added new choices. In this case will i be able to retain the data that is store for old choices like if there is a record with Car type then when i make change will the Category still have Car choice or all the data will be lost?

Comment: The choice column will still have the old data BUT when you edit an item with an old choice, you will be forced to select any of the new values. I Would export the old list with the content to a read-only list as a reference and then make the change.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping the car/bus/truck column and just add the new 'tires' column.

That way you retain the old column metadata and can add new 'tires' data to the existing car/bus/truck records.

Show the columns as required in your view/s.